# Are variables / methods with names beginning with an underscore internal or protected?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Consider the following snippet:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self._i = i

    def _print(self):
        print(self._i)


my_obj = MyClass(5)

print(my_obj._i)
my_obj._print()
```

Is `MyClass._i` and `MyClass._print` considered a protected or internal variable?

According to official Python docs, [Classes § Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name
>   prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a
>   non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a
>   data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and
>   subject to change without notice.

So, the way I understand these docs, preceding a name with an underscore means "internal": intended to be used by the package it is defined in and not outside of this package. And the above snippet is, therefore, correct.

However: PyCharm issues warnings if I open the above snippet:

> ```
> Access to a protected member _i of a class
>
> Access to a protected member _print of a class
> ```

Why "protected"?

Am I missing something? Is there a convention that I'm not aware of that requires me to take extra steps to distinguish between protected and internal?

Comment: Python has no concept of "protected" or "internal" variables. PyCharm has chosen one particular meaning to assign to the leading underscore, which may not be the interpretation you want (it's not the interpretation I usually use).

Comment: PyCharm is not Python; it's taking it upon itself to warn you that you are violating the convention you quoted above. "[p]rotected" is also not being used in any technical sense; PyCharm is just saying you are using an attribute it doesn't think you should be using.

Comment: @chepner "*warn you that you are violating the convention you quoted above.*" - but am I violating this convention? I explained how I understand the convention I quoted above; am I understanding it wrongly?

Comment: @chepner: If it's anything like the corresponding pylint check, it's using "protected" in the Java sense, where a thing should only be accessed from a class or its descendants. (The pylint check allows descendants to access the thing, and the pylint description explicitly mentions subclasses.)

Comment: @gaazkam Yes, you are violating the convention, by accessing `myobj._i` and `myobj._print` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You said in the question:

> So, the way I understand these docs, preceding a name with an underscore means "internal": intended to be used by the package it is defined in and not outside of this package.

Usually "internal" or "protected" attributes or methods of a class are intended to be used **by that class only**, not even outside the class in the whole package/module.

Module attributes and functions: yes, those are intended to be used inside the module only.

That is why you are getting the warnings; the convention is even more restrictive than you seem to think.

---

The script will work regardless, "protected" or "internal" variables and methods are just a convention.

Comment: The version of the convention that *PyCharm* has chosen is that restrictive. This version is not universal. (Also, assuming it works like Pylint, it's not *quite* that restrictive - subclasses are allowed access too.)

Comment: Of course (as with many things in Python), it is not enforced by the language, only suggested by some groups.